# In libxml2, what is the importance of Xpath context, does the context build an index that should be re-used?

Tags: xpath, libxml2, labview

This is a best practices question.  Does the overhead of creating a context for a Xpath search make it recommeded to re-use the Xpath context as often as possible?  Since I'm working in LabVIEW, my code takes a readability hit in coordinating the closing of the context since it's a multi-threaded environment.

It boils down to, are the Xpath query indices built in the context or are indices built in *xmlXPathEval()* calls, to be used in subsequent calls?  Can I, or should I, use the Xpath context in parallel?  *The documentation indicates it's safe to use in parallel but doesn't address index re-use.*

Should I instead, for readability and performance, write an Xpath expression that combines all my results into a CSV-based string?

Answer (score 1):

An XPath context cannot be shared by multiple threads. It also doesn't store any information about the evaluated expression. You can (and should) evaluate different expressions using the same context. Ideally, you have a single context per thread.

If you care about performance, it's important to precompile your XPath expressions with `xmlXPathCompile` and evaluate them with `xmlXPathCompiledEval`. (Maybe that's what you mean by "building an index"?) The `xmlXPathCompExprPtr` representing a compiled expression can be shared across threads.

Comment: Thanks. When I say "building an index", I presume indexing is used somewhere within libxml2 - that Xpath queries aren't merely linear searches for information.  I presume compiling Xpath expressions is only useful if we use it more than once.

Comment: @DannyHolstein 1. No, there's no indexing involved. 2. Yes, if you evaluate an expression only once, you don't get any benefits from compiling it.